# How to read a VSTS tokenised secret build variable from a bash shell script?

Tags: bash, xamarin.android, azure-pipelines

Creating a build definition to build Xamarin.Android project and looking for an option to update the config file with app secrets using a bash shell script. The example given in [Microsoft docs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/variables#set-in-script) indicates that reading a secret build variable from a bash shell script is not possible.

Has anyone tried this before? 
The build agent we are using is a Mac so we need a bash shell script rather than a powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the secret variable through the Arguments. The sample form that article:

Batch (**But I can read %secretSauceArgument%**):

> Arguments:
>
> ```
> "$(sauce)" "$(secretSauce)"
> ```
>
> Scripts:
>
> ```
>  @echo off
>  set sauceArgument=%~1
>     set secretSauceArgument=%~2
>     @echo No problem reading %sauceArgument% or %SAUCE%
>     @echo But I cannot read %SECRETSAUCE%
>     @echo But I can read %secretSauceArgument% (but the log is redacted so I do not spoil the secret)
> ```

Shell (**But I can read $2):**

> Arguments:
>
> ```
> "$(sauce)" "$(secretSauce)"
> ```
>
> Scripts:
>
> ```
>  #!/bin/bash
>     echo "No problem reading $1 or $SAUCE"
>     echo "But I cannot read $SECRETSAUCE"
>     echo "But I can read $2 (but the log is redacted so I do not spoil the secret)"
> ```

Comment: But the echo statement prints the string "I cannot read secretsauce" Does it mean that it cannot access tokenised build variable (secrets ) are not accessible from a shell script?

Comment: @Jeeva Yes, the secretsauce is not accessible from a shell script, you just can read the data from argument ($2)